# Trouble applying boundary conditions to Laplace equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, boundary-conditions

I'm having trouble finding which conditions to apply to Laplace equation in order to find the electrostatic potential of a specific configuration:

There are 4 electrodes, given by the equations (each electrode is a branch of a hyperbola):

$y=\frac{1}{x}$        and              $y=-\frac{1}{x}$

The branches corresponding to the first equation are kept at 5 volts and the other two at -5 volts.
The problem asks you to prove that the potential is given by the function:
$V=Kxy$ , where $K$ is a constant, given the symmetry on the $z$-axis.

Then another configuration is given:

2 electrodes given by the two parts of a two-sheet hyperboloid:
$2z^2-x^2-y^2=2r_0^2$ (kept at a potential of $2V/3$, with $V$ constant) and another one given by the one-sheet hyperboloid: $2z^2-x^2-y^2=-r_o^2$ (at $-V/3$ volts).

How do I apply the given conditions to the solution?

Comment: What is $V(x,y)$ when $xy=1$ ? Does it fix $K$?Is the found function compatible with the other boundary condition?

Comment: Using the given solution, $V(x,1/x) = 5 =K$ and $V(x,-1/x) = -5 = -K$ so K must be 5. That was not my question though. I want to know how to get the function $V=Kxy$ solving Laplace's equation.

Comment: I see. It is by no means obvious that the said solution is the unique one. That is not a standard Dirichlet problem...

Comment: I mean, it is obvious that the said $V$ satisfies both the boundary equations and Laplace equation, if we could use a uniqueness theorm we would conclude. But we cannot, at least easily. The maximum principle cannot be exploited because the domain is not compact and some approximation does not work because the solution cannot be "continuous at infinity"...

Comment: I cannot understand the spirit of the problem.